# Редактирование APK

Tags: android, android-sdk, apk

Имеется APK-файл скачанный с Play Market через онлайн-загрузчик (всё скачалось корректно, пробовал устанавливать). Попробовал декомпилировать пакет и заново его собрать с помощью apktool, batch apktool и APK Editor Studio (использовал последние на настоящий момент версии). И несмотря на то что я не вносил совершенно никаких изменений, при запуске после установки я вижу ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для подписи APK использовал [Apk / Zip File signer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.damylola.signer) прямо на телефоне (APK Editor Studio и batch apktool эту работу выполняют автоматически).

Ссылка на приложение, с которым я работаю: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pedometer.steptracker.calorieburner.stepcounter

Answer (score 1):

### Исправить проблему с неустановленным APK

Сбросив настройки приложения

Шаг 1: Перейдите в «Настройки», нажмите «Приложения и уведомления».

Шаг 2: Нажмите «Просмотреть все приложения».

Шаг 3: В правом верхнем углу нажмите на три точки, затем нажмите «Сбросить настройки приложения».

Шаг 4: Когда откроется диалоговое окно, нажмите «СБРОС ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ».

[тут нашел](https://tech-latest.com/fix-apk-not-installed-problem/)

---

1.1 [Подписание существующего apk с использованием debug.keystore, сгенерированного eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711233/signing-an-existing-apk-using-debug-keystore-generated-by-eclipse)

1.2 [Подпишите свое приложение](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#releasecompile)

Comment: Я попробовал отключить защиту Google Play, распаковать и собрать обратно APK с помощью APK Editor Studio - всё запустилось хорошо. Однако как только я внёс небольшое изменение в исходники (удалил 1 тег в файле с разметкой в расположении Resources/layout/*.xml), я снова получаю ошибку "Файл повреждён" при запуске после установки. Сброс приложений не помог. Я не пробовал самостоятельно подписывать APK. Может ли в этом быть проблема? Дело в том, что APK Editor Studio автоматически подписывает APK.

Comment: Странно, что если заблокировать телефон с открытым приложением и ошибкой, а затем разблокировать - ошибка пропадает и всё начинает работать. Но потом эта ошибка начинает появляться при каждом запуске чаще и чаще.

Comment: Может ли эту ошибку выводить само приложение? Защита от редактирования какая нибудь.

Comment: @D.Stark а как насчет дивайса с которого совершаются попытки запуска апк файла? Он свеж, в плане дров и обновлений?

Comment: Да. Я выяснил, что это сообщение выводит само приложение. В ресурсах есть такая строчка, как на скриншоте. Остаётся обойти встроенную защиту от изменений.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не вносили никаких изменений в APK-файл, то проблема, скорее всего, не связана с неправильным декомпилированием или повреждением файла в процессе пересборки.

Скорее всего, проблема может быть связана с тем, что APK-файл был подписан неправильно или подпись была нарушена в процессе пересборки. При установке APK-файла на устройстве Android проверяется целостность подписи приложения. Если подпись не соответствует оригинальной, то установка приложения завершается неудачей.

Попробуйте проверить подпись APK-файла с помощью команды jarsigner из JDK. Для этого выполните следующую команду в терминале:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs your_app.apk
```

Если вы получите сообщение об ошибке, то это может означать, что подпись APK-файла была нарушена. В этом случае вам нужно будет повторно подписать APK-файл с помощью правильного ключа.

Если же проверка подписи APK-файла проходит успешно, то проблема может быть связана с другими факторами, например, с несовместимостью с версией Android на устройстве. В этом случае попробуйте обновить Android на устройстве до последней версии и повторно установить приложение.

Comment: Проблема возникает не при установке, а при запуске после установки

Comment: По всей видимости дело в том, что есть какая то защита от изменений, так как такое сообщение содержится в ресурсах модуля